# smooth button grow and button shrink animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a fairly simple animation; on mouse over, the button will animate to be bigger. When not hovering, it will return to it's original size. However, whenever when I try this sample code, it warps the button to odd sizes

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'height': $(this).height() * 2,
        'width': $(this).width() * 1.3
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: $(this).height(),
        width: $(this).width()
    }, 300);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RBLqY/1/

how could this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why your code is failing, seems like you have some sort of calculation error when returning to the original size.  After fiddling around a bit I found this solution.  By animating the padding instead of the height and width you don't have to worry about the height width ratio when it comes to resizing the link.

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        padding: '12px'
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        padding: '7px'
    }, 300);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBLqY/11/)

Hope this helps.